# Ограничение стрельбы если игрок смотрит на лево Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть игра платформер, также есть игрок который может стрелять в правую и левую сторону в направление мыши. В правой и левой стороне есть диапазон, условно 30 градусов. Когда игрок стреляет на право, то всё работает отлично, но когда игрок поворачивается на лево, у него не работает ограничение, т.е он может стрелять только в одну сторону(точку), как можно решить эту проблему?

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _offset;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _prefabBullet;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _shootPoint;
    [SerializeField] private float _maxAngle;
    [SerializeField] private CharacterController2D _controller;

    public void Shoot()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 playerToMouse = mousePosition - transform.position;
        playerToMouse.z = 0;

        // Рассчитываем угол между направлением игрока и мышью
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(playerToMouse.y, playerToMouse.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        // Проверяем, находится ли угол в пределах _maxAngle
        if (Mathf.Abs(angle) <= _maxAngle)
        {
            // Вращаем оружие только в пределах _maxAngle
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle));

            // Создаем пулю с направлением, зависящим от направления игрока
            if (angle < 0)
            {
                Instantiate(_prefabBullet, _shootPoint.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, angle)));
            }
            else
            {
                Instantiate(_prefabBullet, _shootPoint.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(180f, 0f, -angle)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Создаем пулю, не изменяя направление
            Instantiate(_prefabBullet, _shootPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```